# What is the shortest malicious XSS possible?

Tags: web-application, xss

Sometimes you stumble upon input fields that don't escape input properly, but who still appear to be to short to actually be used for anything malicious, at least to someone with my limited imagination.

This made me wonder what is the shortest possible input field that can be used to perform a malicious XSS?

Comment: There are a few resources that discuss this: http://labs.neohapsis.com/2012/04/19/xss-shortening-cheatsheet/

Comment: Because it is dependent on the resources available on the web server, this question might be a little broad.

Comment: This sounds perfect for the [Code Golf SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the context.

A very short one:

```
Context:

    <script src="%XSS%"></script>

Let's say you are the owner/maintainer/administrator of http://.to (Tonga gTLD).

    <script src="//to"></script>

XSS with 4 chars. Probably one of the shortest possible.
```

There are dozens of other contexts.

**Edit:** 
Tested on Chrome 38.0.2125.122 (Mac OS X 10.8.5)

Comment: Why do you think `to` would be completed to `to.com`?

Comment: @Gumbo My mistake, I edited the answer. http://to is a gTLD.

Comment: I don't understand the answer, what exactly did you inject? Just the string //to? Why not have the context be <script src="//t%XSS%"></script> and then inject the letter o? Wouldn't that be only 1 character then?

Comment: @jake192 Did you already see your example? Because I already found a bug in Google that proves my point, but in this case I had unlimited chars to exploit the bug, so this is just an example of a short XSS.